# Data Will Not Bind WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Im trying to bind data from a XML file, ive followed tuts from mdsn and other online sources but i keep getting an error, if i bind the data to a listbox it works fine.

```
  public void LoadPage()
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("page01.xml");

        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("page")
                   select new PageReader
                   {
                       PageNumber = (int)query.Element("pnumber"),
                       ChapterTitle = (string)query.Element("ctitle"),   
                       ChapterNumber = (int)query.Element("cnumber")
                   };

        LayoutRoot.DataContext = data;
    }
```

and the XAML

```
  Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFFFFEFE">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FF424242" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="100"  TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="58" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFB6AEAE" FontFamily="{StaticResource lob2}" Text="{Binding ChapterNumber}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="280"  TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="300" MaxHeight="58" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFB6AEAE" FontFamily="{StaticResource lob2}" Text="{Binding ChapterTitle}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="100"  TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="58" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFB6AEAE" FontFamily="{StaticResource lob2}" Text="{Binding PageNumber}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="30"></Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageText" Height="640" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>




</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is of type `IEnumerable<PageReader>`, which is why it would work with a `ListBox` as `ListBox` is expecting a collection.

If you change

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = data;
```

to

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = data.FirstOrDefault();
```

At least you should see some data show up on the UI.